# Do cats produce DMT?

Tags: biochemistry, zoology, feline, hallucinogens

*Edit: If somebody (anybody) wants to add an answer so the bounty won't go to waste, **please** do so! The comments have already introduced me to the Kegg metabolism database, some interesting papers, and an amazing chapter on the biochemistry of cats. Thus, this question has been useful to me (and hopefully, to the community as well).*

> There is a [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15236/do-cats-have-a-chemical-in-their-brains-that-resembles-lsd) on Skeptics.SE that asks if "cats have a chemical in their brains that resembles LSD." I haven't found any similar claim online, but started wondering:
>  
>  1. Do cats produce (natural) compounds that *structurally* resemble LSD?
>  2. Do cats produce (natural) compounds that *functionally* resemble LSD?
>
> Quickly glancing at the structure of LSD, it contains an indole ring. Hovering over the various indoles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole_alkaloid) found one substance that occurred in animals and was consumed as a psychedelic drug.

There is a [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5048497/) that writes:

> N,N-Dimethyltryptamine (DMT) is an indole alkaloid widely found in plants and animals. It is best known for producing brief and intense psychedelic effects when ingested. Increasing evidence suggests that endogenous DMT plays important roles for a number of processes in the periphery and central nervous system, and may act as a neurotransmitter.

The paper also proposed the role of DMT as a neurotransmitter. However, I [haven't been able to confirm](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22N%2CN-Dimethyltryptamine%22+cat) DMT is naturally produced by cats.

**Do cats produce DMT? If so, what is the purpose of DMT in the cat?**

Comment: I suggest you try to answer this yourself using the Kegg metabolism datatbase. I couldn't find anything for Dimethyltryptamine, but searching for [tryptamine](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/search_pathway_text?map=map&keyword=tryptamine&mode=1&viewImage=true) gave eight pathways. I suggest you inspect each to see if there are any related compounds. If you find them, then check which organism the pathway is present in. Even if your search is negative, you'll benefit from the experience. Good luck!

Comment: @David I don't quite understand the Kegg database. It's something like all the signaling/metabolic/synthetic pathways involving tryptamine? I was able to find N-methyltryptamine [here](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/highlight_pathway?scale=1.0&map=map00380&keyword=tryptamine). How would you check for the organisms with the depicted pathway? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Select Felix catus from the drop-down menu "Reference Genome". I did this and the link is [here](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?org_name=fca&mapno=00380&mapscale=1.0&show_description=hide). Enzymes present are highlighted in light green.

Comment: @David Is there a way to specifically find references for N-Methyltryptamine in Felix catus? The website doesn't seem to point to [any](https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?cpd:C06213).

Comment: Just the usual search tools. I tried Pub Med from within my Papers bibliographic app, but only got results for N-methyltryptamine alone, and then only about 40 going back to 1987. All seemed either synthesis in plants or exotic animals like sea sponges, or effects on animals. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: @user1136 Are you suggesting that cats don't have N,N-dimethyltryptamine because they do not develop tolerance when given small doses?

Comment: Why are relevant parts of the question hidden as "spoiler"?

Comment: @user1136 The article is really interesting! Thanks for sharing! "This review comes to the conclusion, that “synthesis of DMT in man has yet to be demonstrated” and that the evidence for the role of DMT in schizophrenia is “currently in-complete”. This pessimistic view, however, is not shared by everybody in the field and further re-search needed to clarify this issue." I'll look for articles that cited this one.

Comment: @Arsak They aren't part of the question I am asking here. I didn't want to cluster it or make it unobvious. But, I didn't want to delete it either.

Comment: Why are cats so important here?

Comment: @AliceD Would it be better to make the question broader? (e.g. Which organisms produce DMT?)

Comment: @AlexAl oh dear, no. That's way too broad. I'm just wondering what the specific relevance is of DMT in felines

Comment: @AliceD I guess I can only say, "I'm curious about cats." And that's the truth, and a bad explanation.

Comment: @user1136 Thanks for the reference! I do find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Many mammals, including cats and humans, produce DMT in small amounts.

DMT has been detected in blood and urine and is produced by the enzyme indolethylamine N‐methyltransferase (INMT). These do bind to serotonin receptors. Serotonin receptors are actually expressed in multiple tissues outside of the brain. However, DMT does cross the blood-brain barrier ([ref](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19276/how-does-dimethyltryptamine-cross-the-blood-brain-barrier)), so it's possible that endogenous DMT has some neuroactive effect (I really don't know). Good question.

[This 2016 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5048497/) states (referring to a 2012 review) that it was identified in urine, blood, and CSF:

> A review by Barker in 2012 assessed 69 studies that reported endogenous DMT detection and quantities reported in urine (29 studies), blood (11 studies), and cerebrospinal fluid (4 studies) from 1955 – 2010 primarily comparing detection levels within healthy controls and schizophrenic patients. DMT in urine was examined in 861 individuals (635 patients), 276 patients and 145 controls were positive for DMT.

I think that's the most direct answer to you question I could find.
I didn't find anything on cats specifically, but that's likely to be similar.

This [earlier 2004 paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00365510510013604) states that it was only found in urine, but the previous study refers to studies before 2004, so I don't know why these two seem to contradict:

> In mammals, endogenous bufotenine and DMT have been identified only in human urine. The DMIAs bind effectively to 5HT receptors and their administration causes a variety of autonomic effects, which may reflect their actual physiological function. Endogenous levels of bufotenine and DMT in blood and a number of animal and human tissues were determined using highly sensitive and specific quantitative mass spectrometric techniques.

Here's the [entry for INMT on Kegg](https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?enzyme%202.1.1.49), and the Human Protein Atlas lists [where INMT is expressed](https://www.proteinatlas.org/ENSG00000241644-INMT/tissue). Weirdly, that enzyme is highly expressed in the human lung.

Comment: As a neuropharmacologist who's specifically studied DMT (doi:10.1021/acs.jmedchem.9b01404), I consider it somewhat unlikely that it's a neurotransmitter, or at least one of any significance.